# rearrange the numbers as specified rules - Combinatorial puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

> 1 
>    8  9 
>    4 7 0 
>  3 5 2 6

Arranged them so that the numbers in a way
that the 3-sides added up alike-that
is, to 16.

Can you rearrange the numbers so that the
3-sides shall sum to the smallest number possible? 
*, Of course, the central barrel (which happens to be 7 above) is not a part of the count.*

3-sides means 3 sides of the triangle...

1,8, 4, 3 is the first 
1, 9, 0, 6 is second 
and 3, 5, 2, 6 is the last...

**@bonus question:** - How many solutions will be there?

Comment: what is a 3-side

Comment: ? = 0 ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis ok editing in more details.. wait

Comment: @TheSimpliFire yes it is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest achievable sum is

> 13

Achieved as follows, one possibility

> 0 
>    8  6 
>   4 9 5 
>  1 7 3 2

Reasoning

> Each of the numbers at the vertices of the triangle are used twice so we should make these as small as possible - namely, assign them to 0, 1 and 2. The number in the middle won't be used at all so we should make this as big as possible - namely 9. Then the sum of the three edges will be 2 $\times$ (0+1+2) + (3+4+5+6+7+8) = 39 so distributing equally, we should make each edge sum to 13.

Number of Solutions

> This comes down to how many ways we can partition the set {3,4,5,6,7,8} into three sets of 2 so that the sums are 10, 11, and 12. There **two** ways of doing this: {(3,8), (4,6), (5,7)} and {(3,7), (4,8), (5,6)}. Within these groups we can swap each of the numbers around so each set corresponds to eight solutions which are geometrically distinct.
>  Hence, there are **16** distinct solutions, up to combinations of rotations and reflections of the triangle.
>  If we count rotations and reflections as distinct solutions, this means there are 6 $\times$ 16 = 96 solutions.